# Best way to do two-way request data encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I want encrypt request content to preventing send raw data through WebAPI requests, so I have to implement tow way encryption.

Which encryption algorithm is good for encrypt high rate of request in asp.net web api and how to implement it?

Comment: "Low way encryption"? As compared to "high way encryption"? Do try and use TLS.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way, requiring no coding on your part, is to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: considering proliferation of MiTM tools, this can not be considered secure at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' way would largely be a matter of opinion, but the standard design i go for is as follows:
The client (the thing making calls) side gets a client cert with private keys. 
The client gets the public key of the server website certificate.
The client gets the public key of the server encryption certificate.

The server (the thing receiving calls) gets the client cert public key.
The server gets the private and public key of the website cert (to be bound in IIS).
The server gets the private key of the server encryption certificate.

In your code, on the server you validate the requests with the presence of exact (thumbprint) and valid (your logic or X509Certificate2 Verify, but beware of CRL/OCSP (if you care about performance, that is)).

On the client, you validate the server website certificate (again, thumbprint plus verification).

Then on the client, as last step before sending a payload, you use the public key of the server encryption cert to PKCS7 envelope a message.
On the server, add a ActionFilterAttribute (to be cleaner) or refactor actions to receive strings (more procedural) and then use the private key of the server encryption cert to unwrap the message.
As the last step in the response, you use the public key of the client cert to PKCS7 envelope a message.

If you're really keen, you can also sign messages with some other certificates but that would really be an obscurity.

This way without getting access to private keys on TWO systems, one can never fully decipher the chat.